# Labeling line twice based on direction in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, direction

**TL;DR**: I would like to put two labels on the same line as on the picture below.

I have three layers:

- Points: `"Point_ID""
- Lines: `"Line_ID""
- Label table (non-spatial): `"ID"`, `"Line_ID"`, `"Start_point_ID"`, `"End_point_ID"`, `"Label"`

Some of the lines are referenced twice in the Label table but with different directionality. I would like to label my lines based on the label direction in the label table, just like on the picture below.

[image]

**My question** is how could I achieve this?

I know I could duplicate the line feature and add an extra attribute based on the joined Label layer with the values like "forward", "backward" but I would like to stay with one line layer.

Is it maybe possible to use geometry generator tool in QGIS? I have the Point_ID-s if I join the Label layer. (I don't seek complete solution to my problem. I just need some guidance.)

Or is there a way more easier way I don't know about? A plugin for example?

Comment: Just to remark: upside down labels are not considered "best-practice" in cartography and should be avoided. I guess you have a reason to still do so.

Comment: Yes, it is strictly for the temporary visualization of the line directionality.

Comment: Using arrows would bei an option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of single labels, use rule-based labeling and create two rules: one for the label `this way`, the second for the label `that way`.

[image]

For the second one, in placement tab, activate `Geometry generator` with this expression to change the line direction: `reverse($geometry)` and be sure to have checked the box `Line orientation dependent postion` (screenshot 1).

On the placement tab, activate `Show upside-down labels` by selctign `always` (screenshot 2).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A way would be something like this (not tested with real data/layers):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lines_with_label AS
SELECT
lns.geometry, lbl.Label
FROM Label_table AS lbl
JOIN Lines_layer AS lns
ON lns.Line_ID = lbl.Line_ID
WHERE
ST_StartPoint(lns.geometry) = 
    (SELECT Points.geometry from Points WHERE Points.Point_ID = lbl.Start_point_ID LIMIT 1)
AND
ST_EndPoint(lns.geometry) = 
    (SELECT Points.geometry from Points WHERE Points.Point_ID = lbl.End_point_ID LIMIT 1)
;
```

which creates a new layer only with lines which have a label associated, aond only if labels are in the correct direction (i.e. `Start_point_ID` is the first point of the corresponding line, and `End_point_ID` the last).
That should work also with polygons, BTW.